# Shell Script Too Many Arguments for if condition

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

My current script does the following;

It takes integer as a command line argument and starts from 1 to N , it checks whether the numbers are divisible by 3, 5 or both of them. It simply prints out Uc for 3, Bes for 5 and UcBes for 3,5. If the command line argument is empty, it does the same operation but the loop goes to 1 to 20.

I am having this error "Too many arguments at line 11,15 and 19".

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
    for i in `seq 1 $1`
    do
        if [ [$i % 3] -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Uc"
        elif [ i % 5 -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Bes"
        elif [ i % 3 -eq 0 ] && [ i % 5 -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "UcBes"
        else
            echo "$i"
        fi
    done
elif [ -z $1 ]
then
    for i in {1..20}
    do
        if [ i % 3 -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Uc"
        elif [ i % 5 -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Bes"
        elif [ i % 3 -eq 0 ] && [ i % 5 -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "UcBes"
        else
            echo "$i"
        fi
    done
else
    echo "heheheh"
fi
```

Comment: @[A. Mesult Konuklar] I edited your question to rollback to previous edit: you may not remove the error from the initial question, otherwise you'll make the overall post unusable to others. Hope you got it by now, but just to explain.

Comment: @J.Chomel, I have no idea what I was doing at that time. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `[` is actually synonym for the `test` builtin in shell (try `which [` in your terminal), and not a conditional syntax like other languages, so you cannot do:

```
if [ [$i % 3] -eq 0 ]; then
```

Moreover, always make sure that there is at least one space between `[`, `]`, and the variables that comprise the logical condition check in between them.

The syntax for evaluating an expression such as modulo is enclosure by `$((...))`, and the variable names inside need not be prefixed by `$`:

```
remainder=$((i % 3))
if [ $remainder -eq 0 ]; then
```

Comment: Thank you, I just leanred `[` meant test in shell. I put space between them normally , but tried without space also :)

Comment: You say variables should not be prefixed within `$((...))`, but both `$(($i%3))` and `$((i%3))` seem to return the same.

Comment: In `bash`, `[` is a builtin, as shown by `help [`, and not as written here a link to the `test` command.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `help [` prints `This is a synonym for the "test" builtin`, at least in bash.

Comment: Yes, you read properly: **builtin** !!! It's not the same as the **command** `[` and `test`. `which` looks for commands in your path...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf edited my answer; I tried looking up the difference between test built vs. test command earlier and couldn't find any answers - can you point me to an appropriate source?

Comment: Here's a reference (the best, actually): http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Unless I missed it in my scanning, I could only find information about the `test` builtin on that page, but no mention of the `test` command - unless what you were trying to say was that there is no such thing as the `test` command, only the builtin.

Comment: `/usr/bin/test` (the command) and `test` (the builtin) are not the same!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm still confused :< I did `man /usr/bin/test` and `man [` and I'm looking at identical man pages.

Comment: `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` are not the bash builtins `test` and `[` (bash builtins don't have man pages). Now, the bash builtins `[` and `test` are the same. The commands `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` might be the same (sometimes they are even linked to each other). On my system, `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` are not the same (don't have the same size), but `man test` and `man [` call the same man page.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use something like :

```
if [ $(($i % 3)) -eq 0 ]
```

instead of

```
if [ $i % 3 -eq 0 ]
if [ [$i % 3] -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, I though I've tried this method also, but I did it like `$((i%3))` silly me. :)

Comment: Actually, as @sampson-chen pointed out in his solution, `$((i%3))` works.

Answer (score 1):

Your script could be greatly simplified.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=0
while test $(( ++n )) -le ${1:-20}; do
  t=$n
  expr $n % 3 > /dev/null || { printf Uc; t=; }
  expr $n % 5 > /dev/null || { printf Bes; t=; }
  echo $t
done
```

gives slightly different error messages if the argument is not an integer, but otherwise behaves the same.