# too many arguments Shell script if check

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to check if the day is Sunday or Friday, and if the time is later than  hour `20`.
If so, then I want to do something; if not, I want to do something else.
I am using `/bin/sh`.

This gives me below error:

> Too many arguments.

Why ?

```
   day_of_week=$(date -d $given_date +%u )
   hour_of_day=${ST_job:0:2}
   if [ [ $day_of_week -eq 7 ] || [ [ $day_of_week -eq 5 ] && [ $hour_of_day -gt 20 ] ] ] ; then
       something
   else
       something else
   fi
```

Thanks

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net  to verify/validate your script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell Script Too Many Arguments for if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405893/shell-script-too-many-arguments-for-if-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` command (aka `[`) does not nest. Anything after the first `[` is treated as an expression and the one you used is syntactically invalid.

Personally, I find complex tests with `[` so ugly, they make me want to find other, more readable and flexible solutions. The `case`/`in` syntax can be used here:

```
case $day_of_week/$hour_of_day in
  (7/* | 5/2[123]) echo "something";;
  (*)              echo "something else";;
esac
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as to why the OP's getting the error ... but it's an excellent solution :)  PS: were you born on the 12th of January, [1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)),or [1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(novel))?

Comment: @FoggyDay See my profile :-) Thanks for picking up a fault in my answer. I shall address it shortly.

Comment: @Jens How does it work if i have to use multiple or ( || ) condition and a and ( && ) condition ? How do i know my && will get clubbed with which || ? One to the left of it or with right of it or all ?

Comment: @Invictus As you can see, you can "or" multiple conditions for the strings using `|`. The "and" condition for day and hour is made by concatenating with a delimiter character (here `/`) and the appropriate pattern to match: 5/21 only matches when the day is 5 AND the hour is 21. You get the idea?

Comment: @Invictus If you ask about the shell list operators `||` and `&&`, they both have equal precedence and the evaluation is stopped as soon as the result is determined. This is called *short-circuiting*. `true || false` does not evaluate the false part. `false && true` does not evaluate the true part. If you insist on using `[` then it is probably more readable to use `-o` for or and `-a` for and, along with `(` for grouping.

Answer (score 3):

You might think "[" is just a grouping, and that you could have different arbitrary nestings.

It isn't.

"[" is an alias for the shell "test" command ... and you need to match them correctly:

> https://www.shellscript.sh/test.html
>
> Test is used by virtually every shell script written. It may not seem
>   that way, because test is not often called directly. test is more
>   frequently called as [. [ is a symbolic link to test, just to make
>   shell programs more readable. It is also normally a shell builtin
>   (which means that the shell itself will interpret [ as meaning test,
>   even if your Unix environment is set up differently):
>
> ```
> $ type [
> [ is a shell builtin
> $ which [
> /usr/bin/[
> $ ls -l /usr/bin/[
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 27 2000 /usr/bin/[ -> test
> $ ls -l /usr/bin/test
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35368 Mar 27  2000 /usr/bin/test
> ```

Look here for more details (and some helpful examples):

[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: 7.4. Nested if/then Condition Tests](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/nestedifthen.html)

Comment: I believe shellscript.sh is suffering a bit from "all the world's a Linux system". Whether `[` is a symlink is not so clear. Some (many? most?) Unixen chose to make it a hard link to `test`. At least FreeBSD does.

Answer (score -1):

Try adjusting your code as following..

```
day_of_week=$(date -d $given_date +%u )
hour_of_day=${ST_job:0:2}
if [[ $day_of_week -eq 7  ||  $day_of_week -eq 5  &&  $hour_of_day -gt 20 ]] ; 
then
  echo  "something"
else
  echo "something else"
fi
```

When putting the arguments in the if condition you don't need to have square brackets again to separate the arguments.